# How can I do Modal DialogFragment (code does not execute til I close it)

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have an activity that popup instructions the first time the app runs ( In a DialogFragment).

I want to stop the execution of code while user don't dismiss the Dialog.

Is it posible to do it???

EDIT: 
I try to use CountDownLatch but it is freezing my UI, and the Dialog is not showing.

Activity :

```
private CountDownLatch startSignal;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // open tutorial if need
    startSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);
        TutorialDialog tutoDial = new TutorialDialog();
    tutoDial.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "tuto");
    try {
        toast("aguardando");
        startSignal.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Dialog ( I just put the needed methods) :

public class TutorialDialog extends DialogFragment {
    private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
    MapActivity parentActivity;
    SharedPreferences preferences;

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    parentActivity = ((MapActivity) activity);
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//      setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, 0);
    AlertDialog.Builder principal = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    principal.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
//      principal.setTitle(R.string.report);
    View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.tutorial, null);
    TextView ok = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.ok);


    ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            parentActivity.resumeCode();  
            dismiss();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog ad = principal.create();
    return ad;

}
```

}

And in the Activity, the method resumeCode():

public void resumeCode(){
        startSignal.countDown();
        toast("whats next");
    }

EDIT 2: I implement it several times. My last implementation should be the one, but it still don't work. I will try to explain how it goes.

mainActivity ( Main thread) launch the dialogFragment:

```
TutorialDialog tutoDial = new TutorialDialog();
        tutoDial.setCancelable(true);
        tutoDial.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "tuto");
```

Then, in another thread, I run await() in onPreExecute():

public class GetPlaces extends AsyncTask> {

```
private ProgressDialog dialog;
    // I put it public so that I can reach it from the DialogFragment
public static CountDownLatch startSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);
```

@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        try {
            startSignal.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.loading));
        dialog.isIndeterminate();
        dialog.setProgressStyle(R.style.dialogInput);
        dialog.show();
    }

This way, it should not run before the startSignal variable reach 0

Then, In my FragmentDialog, when the dialog dismiss, I run :

```
    noTuto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // DISMISS DIALOG
            startSignal.countDown();
            dismiss();
        }
    });
```

So in theory, it should work, but in the ugly reality, my FragmentDialog freeze...

What I'm sure : 
1 - there is no startSignal.await(); in mainActivity that should freeze UI anymore
2 - The startSignal variable is define in another thread:

```
public class GetPlaces extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Place>>
```

so, if anything freeze, it should be this thread, but I don't understand why my dialog is the one which is freezing. Right now, my dialog does not receive clicks anymore...

Comment: The reason your dialog is not showing, is because you are calling `startSignal.await();` in UI thread. Your UI thread is blocked from execution. That's why your UI is freeze, and there is no chance for your Dialog to show up.

Comment: But even if I put it on the onResume() method of the Dialog ( it should display first activity at least, and in onResume, render should already have been done), always freezing.

Comment: Don't call startSignal.await() in UI thread. (onResume to execute by UI thread) Perhaps you should re-phrase your code without using CountDownLatch. Make a clear example on what you are trying to achieve, and what stops you from achieving that.

Comment: So, If I understand well, I should run my DialogFragment in an new thread, block the main thread, and as my Dialog is in a new thread, I will be able to click something that free my UI, am I right???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CountDownLatch startSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);`

Your code will usually be executed in user thread. Make your user thread code `startSignal.await();` so that it can pause its execution.

Your `DialogFragment` will be executed in UI thread. Make your UI thread code `startSignal.countDown()`, to resume your user thread code execution.

Comment: my implementation blocked my UI ! I updated my post.

Comment: I guess I'm blocking UI before he can render views. I tried different ways, always the same...